# How to include linked objects?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

I have a big scene, and about all the objects are linked from a lot of different files...
But know, for transportation and rendering purpose, i wanna include them all into one single file?
it should be a simple solution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>L</kbd> or search for `Make Local` using the space bar menu and choose `All`.